# ERRO: This is application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: c++, qt, dll

Estou com erro ao executar um programa que foi criado com o Qt , ele gera o erro da foto! Esse erro é gerado quando executo o exe, todas as dlls indicadas no dependency walker estão na pasta do exe.

Alguém saberia me ajudar?

Obrigado, desde já.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi Jefferson. Você menciona uma foto, mas não a colocou na pergunta.

Answer (score 8):

À partir da Qt5 você deve ter a seguinte estrutura:

```
+-+ pasta do aplicativo)
  |-- Aplicativo.exe
  |-- Qt5Core.dll
  |-- Qt5Widgets.dll
  |-- outras dlls dos módulos usados
  +-+ platforms
    |-- qwindows.dll
```

A pasta platforms deve estar no mesmo nível do seu .exe, e conter a .dll (no caso do Windows, .so em *nix, etc) referente ao sistema operacional em questão.

No seu caso basta criar a pasta "platforms" junto do aplicativo e colocar a "qwindows.dll" dentro.

**PS:** Detalhe bem observado, mencionado pelo [@LuizVieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/73):

> Sei que a pergunta é sobre Windows. Mas acho que vale lembrar que em *nix não há garantia de funcionar só colocando as bibliotecas compartilhadas na mesma pasta da aplicação. É necessário definir LD_LIBRARY_PATH ([tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)) ou usar a diretiva QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH no .pro ([qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/…](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-lflags-rpath)).